# Optimal algorithm to distinguish given black box access

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory

This is a variant of [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132482/distinguishability-given-black-box-access-to-the-distribution) question. Consider two probability distributions $D$ and $U$, over $n$-bit strings, where $U$ is the uniform distribution. Assume that $D$ and $U$ are far apart in total variation distance, ie,
\begin{equation}
d_{\text{TV}}(D, U) \geq \frac{2}{3}.
\end{equation}

We are not given an explicit description of $D$: we are only given black-box access, ie, we are only given a sampling device that can sample from $D$. Consider a sample $z \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$, taken from either $D$ or $U$. We want to know which one is the case and to do that, we consider polynomial-time algorithms that use the sampling device. I am looking for a single optimal deterministic algorithm that works optimally for all $D$.

Let $A$ be this optimal algorithm. For each $D$, our algorithm $A$ is optimal in the sense that

$$
\Pr_{z \sim D} [A(z) = 1] \geq \frac{3}{4}, \\
\Pr_{z \sim U} [A(z) = 0] \geq \frac{3}{4},
$$

Output $1$ is interpreted as "the sample comes from $D$, and output $0$ is interpreted as "the sample comes from $U$."

Let $A$ use the black-box sampling device a polynomial number of times (at most) and get samples $z_{1}, z_{2}, \ldots, z_{k}$ from $D$, for some polynomial $k$. My intuition is that, if this best algorithm decides that $z$ indeed came from $D$, then it must be true that $z_{i} = z$ for at least one $i \in [k]$. In other words, since we know nothing about $D$ or its support, we have to "see" $z$ at least once in the samples we collect from $D$ to ascertain that $z$ indeed came from $D$. How do I mathematically formalize this statement?

Also, does this same intuition hold if we are given a polynomial number of samples as input (taken from either $D$ or $U$) instead of just one and are also given access to a black-box sampler for $D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $\Omega(2^n)$ samples in order to accomplish your task.

Consider an algorithm that gets $m$ samples from $D$ and then another sample, either from $D$ or from $U$, and has to guess which it is. Its input thus consists of $m+1$ samples $X_1,\ldots,X_m,Y$.

We will generate the distribution $D$ at random by choosing a random set $V \subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ of size $2^{n-2}$ and letting $D$ be a uniform sample from $V$. Note that $d_{\mathrm{TV}}(D,U) = 3/4$.

Consider now the following two distributions:

- Distribution $\mathcal{D}$: Choose $D$ at random as above. Generate $m+1$ samples from $D$.
- Distribution $\mathcal{U}$: Choose $D$ at random as above. Generate $m$ samples from $D$ and one sample from $U$.

Let $S$ be the set of vectors appearing in the first $m$ samples. We can describe the distribution of the final sample as follows:

- Distribution $\mathcal{D}$: With probability $|S|/2^{n-2}$, output a random element in $S$ (each one is output with probability $1/2^{n-2}$). Otherwise, output a random element not in $S$.
- Distribution $\mathcal{U}$: Output a random element.

To see where the alternative description of $\mathcal{D}$ comes from, notice that given $S$, the conditional distribution of $V$ is a random set of size $2^{n-2}$ containing $S$. When sampling a random element from $V$, we have a probability of $|S|/2^{n-2}$ to choose one of the elements from $S$, with probability $1/2^{n-2}$ each. Otherwise, we choose an element from $V \setminus S$, which given the distribution of $V$, is just a random element not in $S$.

This shows that the TV distance between the two distributions is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|S|(1/2^{n-2} - 1/2^n)\right] < \frac{m}{2^{n-2}}.
$$
In particular, any algorithm whatsoever will behave almost the same in both cases unless $m = \Omega(2^n)$. Indeed, your algorithm $A$ satisfies
$$
\Pr_{\mathcal{D}}[A=1] - \Pr_{\mathcal{U}}[A=1] \geq \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2},
$$
showing that the variation distance between $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is at least $1/2$. This is only possible if $m/2^{n-2} \geq 1/2$, that is, if $m \geq 2^{n-3}$.

Comment: Why is the TV $\mathbb{E}\left[|S|(1/2^{n-2} - 1/2^n)\right]$? As in, why the expectation and what is the expectation over? Shouldn't the TV just be $\frac{1}{2}\left[|S|(1/2^{n-2} - 1/2^n)\right]$?

Comment: You might or might not need the $1/2$ factor – it makes little difference anyway. As for the expectation, it is needed since $|S|$ depends on the random variable $V$.

Comment: Even given $V$, the size of $S$ is still random, since it depends on the sample.

Comment: If $V$ is given, the size of $S$ is $m$, right? Which is fixed?

Comment: You can sample the same element twice.

Comment: One more question, when you write that for "Distribution $\mathcal{D}$: With probability $|S|/2^{n-2}$, output a random element in $S$ (each one is output with probability $1/2^{n-2}$). Otherwise, output a random element not in $S$.", how is it equivalent to the other definition of $\mathcal{D}$ in the previous line? $S$ has far less elements than $V$. And $\mathcal{D}$ is just sampling from $D^{\otimes (m+1)}$; so the last element ought to just have distribution $D$.

Comment: This is the magic of the proof. Recall that $V$ itself is also random.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116550/discussion-between-blackhat18-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: Reposting what I wrote on the chat for better visibility. Might it be possible to provide a detailed explanation of why the two descriptions of $\mathcal{D}$ that you have are equivalent? I am still unable to see it.

Comment: I've added some details.

Comment: I guess this is one of the main sources of my confusion: why is $d_{TV}(U, D) = \frac{3}{4}$? Using an argument similar to what you used for $\mathcal{D}$, when sampling from $D$, for each element, we have a probability of $2^{n-2}/2^{n}$ of landing in $V$ given that $V$ is chosen uniformly at random, and a probability of $1/2^{n-2}$ of choosing an element from $V$. Hence, the overall probability is a multiplication of the individual probabilities and is $1/2^{n}$. That makes the TVD $0$?

Comment: Total variation distance is a metric. This means that if $d_{TV}(U,D) = 0$ then $U=D$.

Comment: Right, I'm missing something in my calculation. Is it the fact that I am considering a random $V$ when calculating outcome probabilities for $D$, instead of a fixed $V$ (if I take a fixed $V$, I get $3/4$)? Is the randomly chosen $V$ only for $\mathcal{D}$?

Comment: You might have forgotten the absolute value in the formula.

Comment: When we are calculating the probability of getting a sample from $D$, should we assume that the underlying $V$ is fixed?

Comment: Certainly not. You need to evaluate $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_1,\ldots,x_{m+1}} |\Pr_{\mathcal{D}}[x_1,\ldots,x_{m+1}] - \Pr_{\mathcal{U}}[x_1,\ldots,x_{m+1}]|$.